# How is buffer processing causing different behaviors?

Tags: c, buffer

## The context

I have written a program which takes two coordinates as input and modifies an ASCII world map based on where those coordinates land (land or water):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 22
#define COL 73

#define EMPTY  ' '
#define FILLED '.'
#define LAND   '#'
#define WATER  '~'

void initialize(char map[][COL]);
void show(char map[][COL]);
void colorArea(char map[][COL], int, int, char, char);


int main(void) {
  char map[ROW][COL];
  char type;
  int r, c;

  initialize(map);
  show(map);
  
  while(1) {  
    do {
      printf("\nMax = (%d, %d). Per uscire inserire (0, 0).\n"
             "Inserire le coordinate e premere invio: ", COL, ROW);
      scanf("%d%d", &c, &r);
    } while (r > ROW || c > COL);

    if (r < 1 || c < 1) {
      printf("Arrivederci!\n");
      return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      putchar('\n'); // Clear the screen.

    type = map[--r][--c]; // Could be WATER, LAND, FILLED or EMPTY.

    if (type == EMPTY)
      colorArea(map, r, c, type, WATER);
    else if (type == FILLED)
      colorArea(map, r, c, type, LAND);
    else if (type == LAND)
      colorArea(map, r, c, type, FILLED);
    else if (type == WATER)
      colorArea(map, r, c, type, EMPTY);

    map[r][c] = 'X'; // Mark the point on the map.

    show(map);
  }

  return 0;
}


void initialize(char map[][COL]) {
  char *s[ROW];
  int r, c;

  s[0]  = "                             ..                                          ";
  s[1]  = "         ...   ..        ........                           ..           ";
  s[2]  = "  ...............   ..    .......                   ...............      ";
  s[3]  = " .................  ...    ....          ..     ......................   ";
  s[4]  = " ..  ...................    .           ..   ........................... ";
  s[5]  = "      ................           ..    ............................      ";
  s[6]  = "       .............            ........ ...........................     ";
  s[7]  = "         ......    .          ....................................    .  ";
  s[8]  = "           ...                ...  .  ..........................     ..  ";
  s[9]  = "             ...   .        .....       ......................      .    ";
  s[10] = "               ..            ..................  ............            ";
  s[11] = "                 .....          ...........  .     ....   ...            ";
  s[12] = "                .........         ........          ..     ...           ";
  s[13] = "                ...........        ......           .                    ";
  s[14] = "        .        .........         .....  .                   ..         ";
  s[15] = "                 .......           ....   .               ........       ";
  s[16] = "                 ......             ..                  ............     ";
  s[17] = "                ....                                    ....  .....    . ";
  s[18] = "                ..                                              ..    .. ";
  s[19] = "                .                                                    .   ";
  s[20] = "                                                                         ";
  s[21] = "                                                                         ";

  for (r = 0; r < ROW; r++)
    for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
      map[r][c] = s[r][c];
}

// Print the map.
void show(char map[][COL]) {
  int r, c;

  printf("\n /");
  for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
    printf("–");
  printf("\\\n");
  for (r = 0; r < ROW; r++) {
    printf(" |");
    for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
      printf("%c", map[r][c]);
    printf("|\n");
  }
  printf(" \\");
  for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
    printf("–");
  printf("/\n");
}

void colorArea(char map[][COL], int r, int c, char type, char color) {
  if (c > COL || r > ROW)
    return;

  if (map[r][c] == type) {
    map[r][c] = color;

    colorArea(map, r+1, c, type, color); // Down.
    colorArea(map, r-1, c, type, color); // Up.
    colorArea(map, r, c+1, type, color); // Right.
    colorArea(map, r, c-1, type, color); // Left.
  }
}
```

## The problem(s)

Changing the content of `printf` alters the behavior of the program. If I remove the spacing characters from the `show` function (which prints the map one character away from the left margin) it works unexpectedly:

```
void show(char map[][COL]) {
  int r, c;

  printf("/");
  for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
    printf("-");
  printf("\\\n");
  for (r = 0; r < ROW; r++) {
    printf("|");
    for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
      printf("%c", map[r][c]);
    printf("|\n");
  }
  printf("\\");
  for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
    printf("-");
  printf("/");
}
```

but if doing so I also translate the first `printf` in English

```
printf("\nMax = (%d, %d). Enter (0, 0) to exit.\n"
       "Enter the coordinates: ", COL, ROW);
```

it behaves again as it should. Of course the problem is the language, it's probably due to shortness of the English version, but I can't figure out why. A picture is worth a thousand words, so here it is (the second one is the one with the strange behavior):
[image: Working version]
[image: Problematic version]
Note that this only happens when the coordinates land on water (for example (1, 1)) and the content of `printf` is displayed again if I hit the water again, which make it even more confusing to me. Furthermore, if I enter (0, 0) to exit the program *after* the problem occurs, the program does exit but returns 139 (segmentation fault), but I don't get how it's possible since there is a check with a `return 0;` before calling any function.

## What I figured

Buffer behavior is not standardized. Often buffers process one line at a time, and mine works this way (I tested it with another program). Sometimes characters like `\n` are left in the buffer and cause unwanted behaviors, but it shouldn't be the case here: `scanf` scans for integers, so it should ignore space characters (unlike when it scans for `char`).

## The question(s)

What's causing the problem? What are the two dots that appear? What is happening to the buffer in each step?

Comment: I really didn't know how to phrase the question, I'll change it if you have a clearer alternative.
Also, I got a downvote literally a second after posting, how is it _physically_ possible?
By the way I'm happy to provide more details if necessary

Comment: Changing the content of printf alters the behavior of the program - ok . If I remove the spacing characters from the show function (which prints the map one character away from the left margin) - not clear on this part, is it like adding space before "/" "|" and "\" chars. is it possible to share the code which has issues. ececuted the code and got display messages, correctly.  "Max = (73, 22). Per uscire inserire (0, 0). <> Inserire le coordinate e premere invio:"

Comment: Sure, I've just edited the question

Comment: a 'strange' behavior like that is typical of an undefined behavior, the one you have reading and worst writing out your array so anywhere including other variable(s)

Comment: When you are only printing single characters it is simpler and more efficient to use putchar.

Answer (score 2):

you access out of your array including doing assignment producing undefined behavior, do :

```
void colorArea(char map[][COL], int r, int c, char type, char color) {
  if (c >= COL || r >= ROW || c < 0 || r < 0)
```

and

```
void colorEverything(char map[][COL], int r, int c) {
  if (c >= COL || r >= ROW || c < 0 || r < 0)
```

Also in *show* in `printf("-");` the minus is not the simple ASCII character minus but a complex sequence of character probably produced by your editor (under Windows ?)

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to check for `c < 0 || r < 0` in the recursive function ‍♂️ 
It solves the problem apparently, but I still don't get why it produces that output.

I removed `colorEverything` because I realized it was unnecessary for the question but thanks anyway. The dash was indeed written on Windows, it came from a stub my professor gave me, but it doesn't affect the outoput

Comment: @MDXZ warning you also need `>=` rather than `>`. You had undefined behavior going out of your arrays, so anything can happens including your behavior

Comment: @MDXZ additional tip : install *valgrind* and execute your program under it so replace `./a.out`by `valgrind ./a.out`typically, and you will see your initial program have problems. Always use *valgrind* to check your programs including when you think they are ok